# can client connect from 10.20.0.2 to wcf host on 192.168.0.2?

Tags: wcf, networking

It's possible to mobile client on 10.20.0.2 network connect to wcf service host on other network ? They are connected by usb cord by now and I want test that they can connect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by set in web site binding in IIS ip address and host name 192.168.x.x and find that both - mobile and pc connected throw usb are in the same network :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a network route, I don't see why not, provided that WCF itself can do networking.